# Count rows in a MySQL table that were added today

Tags: mysql

I have a table for users where I have a date type column which stands for the date that they created their accounts and I wanted to count the rows of that table that were added "today" so that I could see how many people created an account everyday.

What's the most effiecient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT count(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE createDate > curdate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just can use `GROUP BY` statement and get count of accounts created per date:

```
SELECT CreateDate, COUNT(*) as UsersCount FROM Users GROUP BY CreateDate;
```